# How to reload a child route's model inside a parent route?

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I have a nested route (see below).

```
this.route('home', {
    path: '/'
}, function() {
    this.route('foo', {
        path: '/foo'
    });
    this.route('bar', {
        path: '/bar'
    });
});
```

The `foo` route model return a collection (array).

Inside parent route `home`, I define a function called `reloadModel`.

I try to reload the model from the controller but failed (produce an undefined function error, `controller.get(...).refresh is not a function` or `controller.get(...).reload is not a function`).

```
    reloadModel() {
        const controller = this.controllerFor('home/a');
        controller.get('model').reload();
    },
```

I would like to reload the child route's model from the parent route; however, I do now know to can I get the child route?

**My Question**

How can I `refresh` model in route `foo` or `bar` from route `home`?

Any hint is appreciated.

Comment: Which function is undefined in your error `get`, `controllerFor` or `reload`?

Comment: I have updated the question. Is this because the `model` I retrived from the controller just a plain object?

Comment: that would definitely cause problems because only Ember Data models have the `reload` method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is usually not a good idea to refresh child route's model from the parent route because it might not have been loaded in the first place. The opposite, refreshing the parent's model from the child, is fine because loading a child route requires, by design, to first load the parent route which will load the parent's model.

Based on your need for such feature, it seems that you're putting yourself in a tough position and should probably think about **WHY** does my design require me to do this, not **HOW** I can do it.

Neverthless, the approach you could use is to, within the parent `home` route, call the same functionality that you call within a child's model route.

If for example route `a` had:

```
model() {
  return this.store.findRecord('a');
}
```

You would do a similar thing in `home`:

```
reloadModel() {
  this.store.findRecord('a', { reload: true }); // skip the cache and make the request
}
```

Comment: Thanks, your answer does make sense to me. I think I need to alter my design instead.

Comment: @LiXinyang glad to help mate. The main thing with Ember is that it's very strict with its design on purpose and tries to push us to the right approach by making all other approaches harder. Thus more times than not anything that is difficult is likely a flaw with our approach and not a lack of capability from Ember. Of course this is not 100% true but it is the general behavior.

Comment: fetchRecord is not a thing in ember-data

Comment: @xoma [yes it is](https://github.com/emberjs/data/blob/v2.10.0/addon/-private/system/store.js#L721) but I guess they are making it a private method. I'll edit accordingly

Comment: @nem035 I just went to the github and tried search for it - it's not on master

Comment: @xoma I attached a link to it in my previous comment. It was just a shorthand helper method for `findRecord('name', { reload: true })` but I guess at some point they chose to remove it from the public API.

Comment: Sorry it got renamed to _fetchRecord - making it private